# Cómo mostrar la suma de horas de dos campos mysql en tkinter

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

Estoy trabajando en un sistema de registro de entradas y salidas. Tengo realizada la mayor parte del proyecto, solo me hace falta realizar una consulta que me pueda sumar las horas que el usuario ha estado dentro del sistema: esto lo realizo gracias a los registros en los campos los cuales son los siguientes: **(id, numeroID, nombre, area, puesto, fecha, horaEntrada, horaSalida)**. Lo que necesito hacer es calcular el tiempo que el usuario está en el sistema para poder mostrarlo por día ya que los usuarios pueden entrar y salir varias veces durante el día, posteriormente debo mostrarlo en una interfaz de Tkinter.
He realizado la consulta en MySQL que ha funcionado correctamente y me ha devuelto lo que necesito:

```
select numeroID, nombre, fecha, horaEntrada, horaSalida, timediff(horaEntrada, horaSalida) as total from accesorf.registro_acceso where fecha between '2022-03-01' and '2022-03-25' and numeroID like 1001 group by fecha;
```

Esto me devuelve lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora al crear la misma función en mi sentencia SQL utilizada en Python Tkinter, me sale algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí el código de python:

```
       mycursor.execute("SELECT `id`, `numeroID`, `nombre`, `area`, `puesto`, `fecha`, `horaEntrada`, `horaSalida`, sec_to_time(time_to_sec(timediff(`horaEntrada`, `horaSalida`))) as `horas_de_trabajo` from registro_acceso where fecha between '2022-03-01' and '2022-03-25' and numeroID like '180648' group by fecha")
```

Utilizo un ciclo "for" para poder mostrar en columnas mis resultados, pero no creo que eso sea lo que esté afectando. No estoy seguro de si es un error con el intérprete de Python o debo cambiar mi consulta.
Aquí el ciclo for:

```
for i, (id, numeroID, nombre, area, puesto, fecha, horaEntrada, horaSalida, horas_de_trabajo) in enumerate(
        records, start=1):
    listBox.insert("", "end", 
    values=(id, numeroID, nombre, area, puesto, fecha, horaEntrada, horaSalida, horas_de_trabajo))
```

También intenté otras consultas como:

```
SELECT 'id', 'numeroID', 'nombre', 'area', 'puesto', 'fecha', 'horaEntrada', 'horaSalida', SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(horaEntrada,horaSalida))))horas_de_trabajo FROM accesorf.registro_acceso where fecha between '2022-03-01' and '2022-03-25' and numeroID like '1001' group by fecha;
```

De igual manera funciona correctamente en mysql pero en mi visualización de tkinter sigue mostrando lo mismo.